Telescopic summation for AGP: $R_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k r^{k-1}$
By the text-book method the summation of AGP is well known as: $$R_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k r^{k-1}=\frac{1-r^n-nr^n(1-r)}{(1-r)^2}.......(*)$$
We can get summation of a GP $(S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} r^{k-1})$ telescopically by writing the successive difference for $t_k$ as:
$$t_k=r^{k-1}=f(k)-f(k-1)=\frac{r^{k}-r^{k-1}}{r-1}~~~~~~~(**)$$
$$r^0=\frac{r^1-r^0}{r-1}$$
$$r^1=\frac{r^2-r^1}{r-1}$$`
$$r^2=\frac{r^3-r^2}{r-1}$$
$$.......................$$
$$.......................$$
$$r^{n-1}=\frac{r^{n}-r^{n-1}}{r-1}$$
By summing all these we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} r^{k-1}=\frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1}$$
The question is: Can we get $R_n$ (*) as a telescopic summation starting with a step like successive difference -ing akin to (**)?

Well, an indirect approach may be to observe that $kr^{k-1}$ is the derivative with respect to $r$ of $r^k$, so switching the order of the derivative and the sum you get the derivative of the GP (which you know how to evaluate using the telescopic method) multiplied by $r$

A good suggestion, I will try  it  out.

A more elegant way to solve this is to multiply and divide by $1-r$. Let me know if you need the details (maybe tag me so I can see your answer more easily)

@Devide Masi Why dont you answer this post, it will be nice.

Sure. Just give some time to format the math

Why down vote a correct query!? Please note every body knows this sum the question is to get correct $F(k)$ such that $kx^{k-1}=F(k+1)-F(k)$.

Yes, one needs to find a correct $F(k)$.

I gave the function at the end of my answer.

It is easier to use the previous result for the geometric partial sum. We expand
$$kr^{k-1} = \frac{kr^{k-1} - kr^k}{1-r}$$
This is creates a telescopic behaviour, because consecutive terms cancel to terms of the geometric sum. Writing this in one equation we get
\begin{align} 
(1-r)R_n &= R_n - r R_n \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n kr^{k-1} - \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1)r^{k-1} \\
&= 1 - nr^n + \sum_{k=2}^n r^{k-1} \\
&= 1-nr^n + \frac{r^n -r}{r-1}
\end{align}
Of course one could just differentiate the  known geometric partial sum formula with respect to $r$.
Note that for all $k > 0$ we have
$$kr^{k-1} = \frac{kr^{k-1}-2kr^k+kr^{k+1}}{(1-r)^2}$$
Summing this equation for $k=1, 2, \dots, n$ telescopes on the right side of the equation. Three consecutive terms with the same power of $r$ cancel. This then gives the final formula. I should mention that is not possible to get any better without using the entire result with the telescope approach, because you need 3 terms to cancel.
Here is the solution that I expect that you wanted (note that this solution can not be found by a bit of sharp looking, so it is not a derivation and only a proof):
Set
$$f(n) = -\frac{(1-r)nr^n +r^n}{(1-r)^2}$$
Then we have
$$kr^{k-1} = f(k)-f(k-1)$$
Now summing those equations for $k=1, 2, \dots, n$ gives a clean telescope and we then have
$$R_n = f(n) - f(0)$$
Done!

Sorry, this isn't telescopic summation.

@ZAhmed I believe this is exactly what was pointed out in the comments.

This will be very ugly, but ok as you want it.

@ZAhmed I included a clean telescope solution now!

Yes, you are finally correct when you get $F(k)=\frac{(r-1)kr^k-r^k}{(r-1)^2}$.

First approach:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n kr^{k-1} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{d}{dr} r^k \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \sum_{k=1}^n r^k \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \sum_{k=1}^n r^{k-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{r^n-1}{r-1} \right) \tag 1 \\
&= \frac{r^n-1}{r-1} + r \frac{d}{dr} \left(\frac{r^n-1}{r-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{r^n-1}{r-1} + r \frac{nr^{n-1}(r-1)-(r^n-1)}{(r-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{(r^n-1)(r-1) + nr^n(r-1)-r(r^n-1)}{(r-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{r^{n+1}-r-r^n+1 - nr^n(1-r)-r^{n+1}+r}{(1-r)^2} \\
&=  \frac{1-r^n - nr^n(1-r)}{(1-r)^2} \qquad \square
\end{align}
Second approach:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n kr^{k-1} &= \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{k=1}^n (1-r)kr^{k-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{k=1}^n kr^{k-1}-kr^k \\
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( 1-r+2r-2r^2+\dotsb+nr^{n-1}-nr^n \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( 1+r+2r^2+\dotsb+nr^{n-1} - nr^n \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n r^{k-1} -nr^n \right) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( \frac{r^n-1}{r-1} - nr^n\right) \tag 1 \\ 
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( \frac{r^n-1-nr^{n+1}+nr^n}{r-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-r} \left( \frac{1-r^n-nr^n(1-r)}{1-r} \right) \\
&= \frac{1-r^n - nr^n(1-r)}{(1-r)^2} \qquad \square
\end{align}
Here $(1)$ is the last formula you wrote in your question.

How can you downvote this? Come on, I spent more than half an hour just to format it and I can't see any issue with it...

Sorry, here we dont see $ kx^(k-1) =F(k+1) -F(k)$, what is F(k)?  One must  cook up the required $bbyeF(k) $. I appreciate your effort and I have not down voted it.

If you want a recursive formula for $kr^{k-1}$ just look at the other answer. Anyway, it is not always possible to find such an easy closed form for sums, so in this case it is convenient to use the known result of the other summation.

@DavideMasi I didn’t downvote and I don’t really see a reason for a downvote without an explanation. Many times you get downvoted for no reason on this platform. One ought not to take it seriously.
